# HttpErrorResponse status returns 406 instead Spring returns 200 status code

Tags: java, angularjs, typescript, spring-boot, http-error

I have been trying to save and retrieve the image from the MySQL DB server, using Angular JS and Spring REST Services.

*The image is getting saved and retrieved successfully* but at the Angular typescript, I am checking the http status as 200 and showing the message "Image Successfully uploaded", since it's getting HttpErrorResponse status 406, I am not able to show the appropriate message on the frontend.

Here in the code below *ImageModel* is a POJO class and *ImageRepository* is a class making use of DAO interface which is implementing the *JpaRepository*.

```
package com.example.fileuploaddemo.controller;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.example.fileuploaddemo.dao.ImageRepository;
import com.example.fileuploaddemo.model.ImageModel;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/api/image")
public class ImageUploadController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageRepository imageRepo;
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/upload")
    public @ResponseBody BodyBuilder uploadImage(@RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Original Image Byte Size - " + file.getBytes().length);
        ImageModel img = new ImageModel(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getContentType(), compressBytes (file.getBytes()));
        imageRepo.save(img);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/{imageName}")
    public ImageModel getImage(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName) throws IOException{
        final Optional<ImageModel> retrievedImage = imageRepo.findByName(imageName);
        ImageModel img = new ImageModel(retrievedImage.get().getName(), retrievedImage.get().getType(),
                decompressBytes(retrievedImage.get().getPicByte()));
        return img;
    }
    
    // compress the image bytes before storing it in the database
    public static byte[] compressBytes(byte[] data) {
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(data);
        deflater.finish();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (!deflater.finished()) {
            int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
        System.out.println("Compressed Image Byte Size - " + outputStream.toByteArray().length);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
        
    }   
    
    
     // uncompress the image bytes before returning it to the angular application
     public static byte[] decompressBytes(byte[] data) {
     Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
     inflater.setInput(data);
     ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     try {
           while (!inflater.finished()) {
               int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
               outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
           }
           outputStream.close();
            } 
     catch (IOException ioe) {}
     catch (DataFormatException e) {}
     return outputStream.toByteArray();
     
     }
    
}
```

Here is my **ImageModel** class :

```
package com.example.fileuploaddemo.model;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "image_table")
public class ImageModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    
    /*image bytes can have large lengths so we specify a value
    which is more than the default length for picByte column*/
    @Column(name="pic_byte", length=1000)
    private byte[] picByte;

    public ImageModel() {
    }

    public ImageModel(String name, String type, byte[] picByte) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.picByte = picByte;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public byte[] getPicByte() {
        return picByte;
    }

    public void setPicByte(byte[] picByte) {
        this.picByte = picByte;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImageModel [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + ", picByte=" + Arrays.toString(picByte)
                + "]";
    }

}
```

And Also attaching the typescript related to the font-end:

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  selectedFile: any;
  retrievedImage: any;
  base64Data: any;
  retrieveResonse: any;
  message: String="";
  imageName: any;

  //Gets called when the user se  lects an image
  public onFileChanged(event:any) {
    //Select File
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }

  //Gets called when the user clicks on submit to upload the image
  onUpload() {
    console.log(this.selectedFile);

    //FormData API provides methods and properties to allow us easily prepare form data to be sent with POST HTTP requests.
    const uploadImageData = new FormData();
    uploadImageData.append('imageFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    //Make a call to the Spring Boot Application to save the image
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/api/image/upload', uploadImageData, { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.message = 'Image uploaded successfully';
        } else {
          this.message = 'Image not uploaded successfully';
        }
      }
      );
  }

    //Gets called when the user clicks on retieve image button to get the image from back end
    getImage() {
      
    //Make a call to Sprinf Boot to get the Image Bytes.
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/image/' + this.imageName)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.retrieveResonse = res;
          this.base64Data = this.retrieveResonse.picByte;
          this.retrievedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.base64Data;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Here is the **error** that I am getting on inspecting the page:

[image]

And in ***STS (spring IDE) console*** getting this *warning* on saving the image:

```
2021-05-24 17:07:58.344  WARN 17488 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

Also **tried to consume the resource using Postman**, getting the status 406 right from my Spring Application; Here is the **Error Message on Postman**:

```
"timestamp": "2021-05-25T17:23:17.541+00:00",
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:315)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
    "path": "/api/image/upload"
}
```

Please Guide me through the resolution of this issue.

Incase, want more clarity about the issue I can provide the github repository link as well.

Thanks !

Comment: You should add, error handling with your HTTP API call in Angular ,

Comment: Can you please guide me about why it's coming as HttpErrorResponse and server status as 406 from my backend!

Comment: Did you try it with postman the file upload?

Comment: Yes I just tried with Postman as well, thanks for pointing it out. And I am getting the same Http error response 406. Now one thing is sure that I am getting this error from my spring application. Could you please help me about how to rectify this Error?

Comment: Spring seems to be failing to convert ImageModel to json. Does this class not have any public getters ? Can you post the implementation of that class ?

Comment: yes sure, providing you the link of github repository and at the same time I am updating the ImageModel implementation here as well! [link](https://github.com/000GEV744/Spring-Git/blob/main/File-Upload/fileupload-demo/src/main/java/com/example/fileuploaddemo/model/ImageModel.java) @lorefnon